# How to call a overrided virtual function from a base class function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

I just realized that I simplified the code too much and that it does not reflect my real problem. I apologize for not being more specific. What I actually tries to do is the following:

**[online Demo](http://codepad.org/GqPZzoS8)**:

```
#include<iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        A();

        virtual void f()= 0;
        void g();
};

A::A()
{
    g();
}

void A::g()
{
    f();
}

class B : public A
{
    public:
        B() {};
        void f() {};
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

I guess the program calls the pure virtual function `A::f` since `B` has not yet been created when the constructor is called.

Is this correct and how can I overcome this problem?

Please forgive me for giving the too simplified problem earlier.

Comment: I'm waiting for a response too. For what I know about C++ you can't construct a class instance where the class has still some unimplemented pure virtual methods..

Comment: There's almost definitely a bug in code you removed.

Comment: No, this most definitely does not compile. Perhaps some related program does indeed compile. If so, please show it verbatim.

Comment: @Heisenbug +1, I was wondering how the original poster got it to compile as well

Comment: I took the liberty of modifying your Question to add an appropriate code sample and Also, updated my answer which answers it.

Answer (score 5):

**[Working sample](http://codepad.org/NJjtZO4q)** of your code, after I removed lot of other errors.

```
#include<iostream>

class A 
{
    virtual void f()=0;
    public:
    void g();
};

void A::g() 
{
   f();
}

class B : public A 
{

    void f(){std::cout<<"Inside B::f";}
};

int main() 
{
    B b;
    b.g();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> Inside B::f

Post your *real* code, to get *real* answers.

---

**EDIT:**
Now, that you showed us your real code(it had compilation errors,I fixed them for you). I understand your problem.

When you create an object of class `B` using `B b;`, it results in calling the base class constructor `A::A()`, which in turn calls the method `g()`. Note that `g()` is only a Base class method so this results in call to `A::g()`. This further calls `f()`. Now your expectation is this should call `B::f()` but it doesn't.

**WHY?**
Note the rule,
**Inside the constructor or destructor the type of object `this` points to is always the type whose constructor/destructor is being called.**

Applying the above rule, Since `f()` is called in the constructor of `A`,
`this->f()` calls `A::f()` and not `B::f()`. Further since `A::f()` does not have a definition(Since you didn't provide one) It results in a run-time exception:

> pure virtual method called
>   terminate called without an active exception.

The compiler could not detect this as compile time error because with `virtual` the function to be called is determined at run-time depending on what `this` points to and not statically. There was no way the compiler could detect this.

**How can I overcome this problem?**
You cannot do it through dynamic dispatch in Constructor.
You can achieve and expect the behavior you are expecting if you called it from any other method except constructor/destructor.

Avoid calling virtual functions in constructors and destructors because they do not call versions which you *think* they might call.

Answer (score 0):

If the function signature of B::f matches A::f, then using f() in A::g should invoke B::f as you want it to. In your example above they do match and A::g should call B::f.

If your real function signatures are more complex than the example given above, make sure their signatures match exactly, or the compiler will consider B::f to be a new function instead of an override of A::f.

*: strictly speaking, the return type can be slightly different, but I expect that's not relevant here

Answer (score 0):

After removing compiler errors, [your code works fine](http://www.ideone.com/80A7I).

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually this should work. I haven't been in C++ in ages, but this shouldn't be very different from this scenario in C#:

```
public class MyBase
{
    public virtual void PrintName() { }
    public void DoWork()
    {
        PrintName();
    }
}

public class MyDerivative : MyBase
{
    public override void PrintName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyDerivative");
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course in C# you'd mark MyBase and MyBase::PrintName as abstract.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    void g();
};

void A::g() {
    std::cout << "A::g" << std::endl;
    this->f();
}

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void f();
};

void B::f()
{
    std::cout << "B::f" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    B b;
    b.g();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in the source :

```
void B::f()
{
    printf("im B::f\n");
}
```

and your program should work.

you cannot create instances of A because there is a pure virtual method.